# Updating values inside a list comprehension

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, loops

I am wondering whether it is possible to update values inside a list comprehension.

I am thinking of something like:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,1,0]
ans = [0]*(n+m-1)
print [ans[i+j] += a[i]*b[j] for i in xrange(len(a)) for j in xrange(len(b))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.
A comprehension list provides a concise way to create lists.

In your case though, you could still use a comprehension list to create the list (not to update it):

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,1,0]
ans = [sum((a[i]* b[s-i] for i in range(max(0, s-len(b)+1), min(len(a),s+1)))) for s in range(len(a)+len(b)-1)]
print ans
```